# Can not run asp.net application using Local IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool

[image]

I can't debug my application using a local IIS server. However, when I change to IIS Express I can debug my application.

I'm running Visual Studio as an administrator.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting a specific error message? Where did you get your "hint"?

Comment: please be more specific and provide sample code

Comment: I attached an image of the error

Comment: Are you running VS as an Administrator?

Comment: Yes running it as Administation

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post a part of you web.config file where you are setting up end points to IIS>

Comment: Did you make sure you can use IIS outside of the context of debugging? IIS has to be installed and running for this feature to work. IIS is not enabled on windows by default for home users, and is not even available for some windows versions.

Comment: Start with this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx make sure your IIS is installed and configured. You should be able to access it with localhost and serve a static file. Once you can do that, try serving a ASP.NET file. If it fails, make sure .NET and ASP.NET is installed.

Comment: sorry i don't know where is the problem but all i can see that the application can debug using iis express but when i create a virtual directory and trying to debug it, it doesn't debug 
i was debug it before using local iis and Vs was running as administration, but now i can't do it

Comment: Are there any errors logged in the event viewer or in any log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have to do is:

register asp.net first to iis server like this;

1. run cmd as administrator.
   [image]
2. in IIS >>> application pools >>> .net framework.. check your project framework here if the same of your project framework setting.

Answer (score 0):

use debug/attach to process and attach your vs to all instances of w3wp.exe